# How to use iconv in Qt?

Tags: qt, mingw, iconv

I've installed [qt-sdk-win-opensource-2010.03](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/downloads#lgpl) and found an libiconv-2.dll in mingw part of qt distribution.

How do I use it (I can't find iconv.h)?

Is there a static version of iconv library?

Answer (score 0):

I believe iconv library is used by Qt itself for [Unicode](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/unicode.html) functions. If you you are using Qt already, may as well use its Unicode functions since they are much easier to work with.

Comment: What if you wanted to convert from another encoding to Unicode? I know iconv can do it but is there a way to do it in Qt? For example I routinely need to convert Shift-JIS to UTF8, but I'm having problems with iconv on windows working correctly (linux is fine).

Comment: QTextCodec should be able to do it: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtextcodec.html

Comment: Ah, I meant CP932, not Shift-JIS. It seems not supported.

Comment: I never actually used it but CP932 seems to be part of JIS codec: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/codecs-jis.html